# Disable checkbox based on db value

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox in a form which I need to disable based on the value in the database. I searched a lot, but can't find any solution that works. Here's the sample code:

```
<?php
$server_name='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$db_name='checkbox';
$con= mysqli_connect($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Failed..!!'.mysqli_connect_errno();
}    

$result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM checkbox WHERE status=1");
$display = (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1);
$disable = $display?'':'disabled="disabled"';
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form name="f1" method="post" action="test2.php">
        <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="" <?php echo $disable; ?> />     
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Far as I can tell, it seems that you may have gotten your ternary's order mixed up.

Now this line is redundant:

```
$display = (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1);
```

You're telling it that it always equals TRUE.

Just set this line to:

```
$display = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Then the ternary operator will take care of *if it's found or not*:

```
$disable = $display ? 'disabled="disabled"': '';
```

...and if found, disable it.

If that isn't what you're looking to do, then change it back to:

```
$disable = $display ? '': 'disabled="disabled"';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM checkbox WHERE status=1");
$display = (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1);
```

Is likely the cause of your problems though it can't be 100% without looking in the database. Does that query return something other than one row? If it does your $display variable will always evaluate to false and not add that disable text to the input field.

Wrap the $disable variable in a var_dump() before you get to the rendering of HTML and see what value you are getting. Or do a direct database query with the one you are triggering off of and see if it is something other than one row.